# Using AddTicks does not cause difference to DateTime

Tags: c#

I have following code for `AddTicks` method. Ticks property of datetime object is returning same value before and after the AddTick method. Why is it behaving so?

> There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
>
> Ticks: The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, which represents DateTime.MinValue.
>
> AddTicks : Adds the specified number of ticks to the value of this instance.

Note: I am using `.Net 4.0` framework

**CODE**

```
    static void Main()
    {


        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2010, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12, 222);

        long x = dt2.Ticks;
        dt2.AddTicks(9999);

        long y = dt2.Ticks;

        bool isSame = false;
        if (x == y)
        {
            isSame = true;  
        }


        Console.WriteLine(isSame);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`AddTicks` (and the other `Add*` methods) does not alter the DateTime, but returns a new object.

So you should use

```
dt2 = dt2.AddTicks(...)
```

`DateTime` is a value type and is immutable.

Comment: DateTime, as other native structs are immutable.

Comment: @SteveB However, there are a few (unfortunate) examples of mutable structs. For example, with a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` and `using System.Drawing;`, the following actually modifies an existing `Point` value: `Point p = new Point(60, 20); p.Offset(3, 4);`

Answer (score 3):

DateTime values (like strings) are immutable.

Any operation on a DateTime instance won't change the value of that instance, but instead will return a new DateTime value that you have to capture.

```
dt2 = dt2.AddTicks(9999);
```